# Data pkt lost when one of the side send TCP Reset After network restart

Tags: sockets, tcp, mina, apache-mina

i have a setup where Host_A and Host_B are in TCP session. Then i pulled out network cable on Host_B side for 30 sec time and put it back and capture the wireshark. Very first pkt in wireshark is some data pkt from Host_A and then Host_B ack as TCP RST. Then Host_A send TCP SYN and intitate a new TCP session. But Host_B already lost the data pkt that Host_A was trying to send.

How can i make Host_B to receive data pkt successfully in above case. 
For TCP prtocol i am using Apache Mina wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

TCP RST means that connection is not exist now. This is because Host_B's application closed connection by timeout.

SYN request means new connection is established:

You have two choises:

- Increase timeout on Host_B.
- Resend data after new connection is established from Host_A.